# How to get Parent Row position in an expandable list view when an item in the parent row is clicked?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am using an ExpandableListView. I have four items on the view. Here is the xml file for the parent row of list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/saved_tank_mixes_parent_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin" >

    <com.lht.textview.LHTTextView
        android:id="@+id/saved_mix_name_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/brown_for_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:fontFamily="helveticaltstdlight.ttf" />

    <com.lht.textview.LHTTextView
        android:id="@+id/saved_mix_time_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/saved_mix_name_textview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="Saved 15 mins ago"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_extra_lite"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:fontFamily="helveticaltstdlightcond.ttf" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/detail_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cross_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onDeleteSavedMixClick"
        android:background="@drawable/cross_button_selector"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Last button (Here, cross button) is for deleting items from list view.

I want to get the position of the list row when I click on this cross button. I tried implementing onGroupClickListener to get the position, but its not working. Please help me with this.

Below is the code for my custom adapter.

```
package com.lht.precisionlabs.mixtank.savedrecipe;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.lht.precisionlabs.mixtank.R;

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listViewDataItem;
    private boolean isDeleteButtonVisible=false;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listViewDataSource)
    {
        this.mContext=context;
        this.listViewDataItem=listViewDataSource;
    }

    public void setDeleteButtonVisibility(boolean isVisible)
    {
        this.isDeleteButtonVisible=isVisible;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getDataSource()
    {
        return listViewDataItem;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_tank_mix_child_row_layout, parent,false);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listViewDataItem.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listViewDataItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_tank_mixes_base_row,parent,false);
        }
        setDataOnView(convertView,groupPosition,isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    private void setDataOnView(View view,int groupPosition,boolean isExpanded)
    {
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)view;
        TextView textView=(TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.saved_mix_name_textview);
        textView.setText((String)(listViewDataItem.get(groupPosition).get(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.mix_name_key))));
        textView=(TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.saved_mix_time_textview);
        textView.setText((String)(listViewDataItem.get(groupPosition).get(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.mix_date_key))));
        ImageView detailIcon=(ImageView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.detail_icon);
        Button deleteButton=(Button)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.cross_button);
        if(isDeleteButtonVisible)
        {
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            detailIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(isExpanded)
                detailIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                detailIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: have your tried onChildClick method..?

Comment: onChildClick method will call the child row of the list and I am restricting the list to open when delete mode is on. And implementing child click will invoke this function whenever an item of child row is clicked, while I have to get different functions done on the child row element's selection. OnChildClick works for child row so far as I think and not for parent row. I have this cross_button in parent row and I want the row position on this button click.

Comment: show your getview method..

Comment: Thanks, I checked for onChildClick method, hope so it works, I am trying.

Comment: okey..all the best.. ;)

Comment: onChildClick is not working..

Comment: then show your getview method plz..

Comment: I am using a custom adapter.

Comment: yeah, i know that.. put that custom adapter whole code..